# Create an app that will answer an incoming call via speech recognition from user? Possible?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I am a student and i would like to ask if it is possible to develop an app that will take an incoming call through the speech intervention of the user eliminating the use of physical input from the user?
For example using the keywords ("Answer/Reject")
Also what are the starting points to develop this application? Thank you for understanding :)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Not knowing your background, we'd need to write an entire book to tell you what to do. Do you know Java? Can you run an "Hello World" program? What other applications have you written so far in Android or in other languages? If this is your first program, I'd suggest you start with an app that is a bit simpler, like a simple calculator or something.

Comment: Ow, sorry i have basic knowledge about developing android applications like, simple bluetooth on/off apps, Basic GPS activities,Calculators, most likely the ones thought in school.

Comment: Ok, so then you need to learn about Broadcast Receivers to detect the incoming call and you need to learn about the android.speech api in order to recognize your own speech. If you're not familiar with those topics yet, I'd suggest you google each of them along with the word "tutorial" appended to your query. Also, you may need to think through your use cases a little bit. What happens if you get a call and your phone is in your pocket? Do you still want to activate the call by voice? What happens if your phone is ringing, and the ringing sound is interfering with the speech api?

Comment: Ah okay thank you, the module will be  used for dormant mode purposes while driving.Btw thanks :)

Comment: The one thing I don't know about for sure is if you're allowed to accept the phone call programmatically (but I have a feeling that's probably possible since bluetooth allows you to accept calls at a press of a button, so there is probably a programmatic way to launch that intent)